# What causes the wrong count for the groupby and transform.count() operation in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am grouping and counting on my dataframe.

This is what I get from the .describe() method:

While all the other metrics are 4. In fact, there are only 4 barcodes in this group, so the count should be 5. How can it be that the count is 5?

```
invoice_number        barcode
OFF1540673            4054673005837  count                                   5.0
                                     mean                                    4.0
                                     std                                     0.0
                                     min                                     4.0
                                     25%                                     4.0
                                     50%                                     4.0
                                     75%                                     4.0
                                     max                                     4.0
                      4054673034394  count                                   5.0
                                     mean                                    4.0
                                     std                                     0.0
                                     min                                     4.0
                                     25%                                     4.0
                                     50%                                     4.0
                                     75%                                     4.0
                                     max                                     4.0
                      4054673238488  count                                   5.0
                                     mean                                    4.0
                                     std                                     0.0
                                     min                                     4.0
                                     25%                                     4.0
                                     50%                                     4.0
                                     75%                                     4.0
                                     max                                     4.0
                      4054673238822  count                                   5.0
                                     mean                                    4.0
                                     std                                     0.0
                                     min                                     4.0
                                     25%                                     4.0
                                     50%                                     4.0
                                     75%                                     4.0
                                     max                                     4.0
```

**Update**

Original Dataset

```
              invoice_number  barcode
327378            OFF1540673  4054673238488
327379            OFF1540673  4054673034394
327380            OFF1540673  4054673238822
327381            OFF1540673  4054673005837
327382            OFF1540673  4054673238488
327383            OFF1540673  4054673034394
327384            OFF1540673  4054673238822
327385            OFF1540673  4054673005837
327386            OFF1540673  4054673238488
327387            OFF1540673  4054673034394
327388            OFF1540673  4054673238822
327389            OFF1540673  4054673005837
327390            OFF1540673  4054673238488
327391            OFF1540673  4054673034394
327392            OFF1540673  4054673238822
327393            OFF1540673  4054673005837
327394            OFF1540673  4054673238488
327395            OFF1540673  4054673034394
327396            OFF1540673  4054673238822
327397            OFF1540673  4054673005837
```

dtypes for both colums is "object"

this is the command to group...

print data.groupby(['invoice_number','barcode'])['invoice_number'].describe()

Comment: How looks your data before `describe`? I try simulate it `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4] * 10, 'b': ['a'] * 5 + ['b'] * 5})` - It seems all values are `4` and `length` of each `group` is `5` (or more if `NaN`s)

Comment: `print (df.groupby('b')['a'].describe())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [I want to know the distinct number of barcodes per order number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585740/what-causes-the-wrong-count-for-the-groupby-and-transform-count-operation-in-p/43585823#comment74221381_43585823)

```
In [30]: df.groupby('invoice_number')['barcode'].nunique()
Out[30]:
invoice_number
OFF1540673    4
Name: barcode, dtype: int64
```

**UPDATE:** can't reproduce your issue using provided data set:

```
In [16]: df.groupby(['invoice_number','barcode'])['invoice_number'].describe()
Out[16]:
invoice_number  barcode
OFF1540673      4054673005837  count              5
                               unique             1
                               top       OFF1540673
                               freq               5
                4054673034394  count              5
                               unique             1
                               top       OFF1540673
                               freq               5
                4054673238488  count              5
                               unique             1
                               top       OFF1540673
                               freq               5
                4054673238822  count              5
                               unique             1
                               top       OFF1540673
                               freq               5
Name: invoice_number, dtype: object

In [17]: df.groupby(['invoice_number','barcode'])['invoice_number'].count()
Out[17]:
invoice_number  barcode
OFF1540673      4054673005837    5
                4054673034394    5
                4054673238488    5
                4054673238822    5
Name: invoice_number, dtype: int64
```

Comment: The group contains 4 barcodes (see above), but the count is 5 instead of 4. Does it really have to do with NaNs?

Comment: @Jabb, thanks for the data set! I couldn't reproduce your issue - please see UPDATE

Comment: in your reproduction, the count is 5, while there are 4 barcodes. Shouldn't the count be 4?

Comment: ahhh! I am looking for something different... I want to know the distict number of barcodes per order number

Comment: @Jabb, do you mean this: `df.groupby('invoice_number')['barcode'].nunique()`?

Comment: exactly. I am sorry for the confusion. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!